# direct /dev/input/event0 to STDIN

Tags: redirect, input, ncurses

/dev/input/event0 is usb keyboard.
/dev/tty0 is LCD screen.

I would to **redirect STDIN** to /dev/input/event0 and redirect STDOUT to /dev/tty0.

### This my try:

```
[root@TR600-Plus ~]#./a.out > /dev/tty0  
[root@TR600-Plus ~]# ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd  
total 0  
0 -> /dev/pts/0  
1 -> /dev/tty0  
2 -> /dev/pts/0
```

redirect STDOUT is work. **But STDIN how to change?**

**I try use this command to change STDIN:** but don't work...

`[root@TR600-Plus ~]#./a.out /dev/input/event0>&0 > /dev/tty0`

My project work on ncurses. My purpose is that **getchar()** can get key value from USB keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell command is going in the wrong direction, e.g., it should be something like

```
./a.out < /dev/input/event0 > /dev/tty0
```

But you might get better results using `newterm` in your application (and open the devices directly) than rely on passing a stream via the shell and using `initscr`.

Answer (score 1):

---

I create **newterm** through pesudo terminal can solve my purpose.

## Task 1:

```

```
// create pesudo terminal
    fd = open("/dev/ptmx", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    grantpt(fd);
    unlockpt(fd);
    char *pts_name = ptsname(fd);
    printf("ptsname: %s\n", pts_name);

    // redirect STDIN to /dev/pts/2
    dup2(fp, STDIN_FILENO);

    while(1) {
        getchar();
    }
```

```

## Task 2:

```

```
fpevent = open("/dev/input/event0", O_RDWR);
fppts   = open("/dev/pts/2", O_RDONLY);
// ayalyse what key press
read(fpevent,...)
scan_code = analyse(...);
// transmission ASCII code to pesudo terminal
v_key = scan_code_2_virtual_key(scan_code);
write(fppts, v_key, 1);
```

```